# Get Array Length using Templates (Assignment)

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code that gets the length of an array with any type. I can't change anything in the main function since this is an assignment. The code I wrote is the implementation of `array_length`. I do not understand why I can get the length of both the `int` and the `double` but not the length of the `char` array. I am assuming that it has to do something with the fact that `int` and `double`'s 0 is just zero. It means, the value is zero. But char '0' is not zero. '0' is an ASCII code, so '0' has a value 48 or 0x30. I am not sure though. I appreciate any help.

Here is my entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T, size_t N>
    T array_length(T (&arr)[N]){

    
    T length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(T);
    
    return length;
}

int main()
{
    int a[6]={2,7,4,2,2,0}; char b[8]="GEBD030";
    double c[7]={4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 0.0};
    cout << "a:" << array_length(a) << endl;
    cout << "b:" << array_length(b) << endl;
    cout << "c:" << array_length(c) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already have the "length" (number of elements) of the array in the template argument `N`. There's no need to do any calculations.

Comment: Pay attention to types. `T array_length(T (&arr)[N])` says "the length of an array of ints is an int, the length of an array of strings is a string, the length of an array of students is a student,..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `array_length` is `T`, when being passed a `char` array, the return type would be `char`. Then `std::out` would print the return value as a `char` with ASCII code `8`.

Change the return type to `std::size_t`.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
size_t array_length(T (&arr)[N]){
    ...
}
```

---

BTW: As the implementation, you can just return the template parameter `N`. e.g.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
size_t array_length(T (&arr)[N]){
    return N;
}
```